# reactstrap and Chrome auto-fill puts password in email input

Tags: reactjs, forms, reactstrap

In my React application (using [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) and bootstrap), I have a login form which contains two fields, email, and password.

```
<Input
   type="email"
   name="email"
   id="emailInput"
   onChange={this.handleInputChange}
   value={this.state.email}
   placeholder="email"/>
```

when component renders the chrome auto-fills the fields, the state of email changes to what chrome put, and component re-renders.

Here according to some logic in the login component, the email state may change to an empty string again `this.setState({email:''})`.

Now the password is still there but clicking on email field (which is now empty) the chrome autofill pops up and shows the email/password saved and on click, the **password** is filled in the email field **instead of email**.

using standard HTML `input` tag does not have that problem. I have not tried with other UI libraries, but for reactstrap `Input`.

Anyone had such experience?

[the propTypes of reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/form/#Properties)

P.S.

```
  handleInputChange = ({ target: { name, value } }: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
  };
```

Comment: What is the code of your `handleInputChange` function?

Comment: @Rallen added to question

Comment: Could not reproduce your error. You should try to empty the password storage in chrome on whatever url the issue occurs and try again.

Comment: I have done that, after saving password again the same problem happens, though this is not happening in Firefox